# An integral involving square roots and a product of two arc tangent functions.

Tags: integration, special-functions

Let $c>0$. In the process of solving a problem [related to Gaussian integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3813158/an-integral-involving-a-gaussian-and-a-power-of-a-normal-cumulative-distribution) we came across the following integral:

\begin{eqnarray}
{\mathcal I}(c) &:=& \int\limits_0^c \frac{t }{\sqrt{2 t^2+1} \left(3 t^2+1\right) \sqrt{4 t^2+1} } \cdot \arctan\left(\sqrt{2 t^2+1}\right) \cdot \arctan\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{4 t^2+1}}\right) dt \quad (i)\\
\end{eqnarray}

Observation: The left-most term in the integrand has a neat anti-derivative given below:

\begin{equation}
\int  \frac{t }{\sqrt{2 t^2+1} \left(3 t^2+1\right) \sqrt{4 t^2+1} } dt = \frac{1}{2} \arctan \left(\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{2 t^2+1} \sqrt{4 t^2+1}}\right)
\end{equation}

and therefore there is hope that something can be done using integration by parts.

How would you go about solving  integral $(i)$ ?

Comment: Assuming the integral identity you give above is correct,integration by parts yields
$$I(c)=\frac{1}{2}\arctan\left(\sqrt{2 t^2+1}\right) \cdot \arctan\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{4 t^2+1}}\right)\cdot\arctan \left(\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{2 t^2+1} \sqrt{4 t^2+1}}\right)\bigg|^c_0$$
$$-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^c \arctan \left(\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{2 t^2+1} \sqrt{4 t^2+1}}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{4t^2+1}}\right)}{2(t^2+1)}+\frac{5t^2+1}{4t^2+1}\arctan\left(\sqrt{2t^2+1}\right)\right)\mathrm{d}t$$
But I don't really see how this helps.

Comment: Numerical experiments suggest $I$ approaches a limit of $\approx 0.0575$ as $c$ gets large and it approaches this value rather quickly. See [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/uzh4gfqm03)

Comment: Yes, thank you for this.I have a gut feeling that this problem involves poly-logarithms of order three.