# How to compute $\int \sqrt x e^{-x/2} \operatorname{erfc}(\sqrt{x/2})^{m}dx $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, error-function

Hello I want to compute

$\int_0^\infty \sqrt xe^{-x/2} (\operatorname{erfc}(\sqrt{x/2}))^{m}dx $ where $\operatorname{erfc}(x)=1-\operatorname{erf}(x)$ with $\operatorname{erf}(x)$ the standard error function and $m$ is a fixed non-negative integer.

So far I tried substituting in a smart way but I could not find one. The same happens with pratial integration. My problem there is the $m$ in the exponent.

Comment: You can write \operatorname{erfc} for nicer formatting. Otherwise it's rendered as $e$ times $r$ times $f$ times $c$.

Comment: Why $m-1$? Why not just $m$? Is $m$ an integer? Can it be negative?

Comment: Hello, this $m-1$ resulted from previous computations, you can substitute with $z:=m-1$ and $z \in \mathbb{Z}, z \geq 0$.

Comment: @samabu I revised the question accordingly.

Comment: Ok thank you for this

Comment: For general `m` I doubt there's a closed form for integral. See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/696630/how-to-evaluate-int-0-infty-operatornameerfcn-x-mathrm-dx?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

As already said in comments, very little hope for a closed form for
$$I_m=\int \sqrt{x}\,e^{-x/2}\Bigg[  \text{erfc}\left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{2}}\right)\Bigg]^{m-1} \,dx$$ which could look nicer using $x=2y^2$
$$I_m=4 \sqrt{2}\int y^2\,e^{-y^2}  \Big[\text{erfc}(y)\Big]^{m-1}\,dy$$ Using
$$\text{erfc}(y)=1+\frac 2 {\sqrt \pi}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac{y^{2 n+1}}{(2 n+1)\, n!}$$ and using the binomial expansion of
$\Big[\text{erfc}(y)\Big]^{m-1}$,
we should face integrals
$$J_k=\int y^{2+k}\,e^{-y^2}\,dy=-\frac{1}{2} \Gamma \left(\frac{k+3}{2},y^2\right)\qquad \text{with} \qquad k \text{  from }0 \text{ to } \infty$$

I tried for $m=4$ and integrated from $x=0$ to $x=2$  truncating the expansion to  $O(y^{21})$.

The decimal representation of the result is $0.0746951$ while the numerical integration would give  $I_4=0.0756388$ (relative error of $1.26$%).

Comment: Hello, thank you ver much for your answer. Even if the answer is no, at least it is an answer :) . I think you are having a computational error in your solution. If you set $x=2y^2$ then $\sqrt x = \sqrt 2 y$ and not $4 \sqrt 2y^2$ .

Comment: @samabu. I checked again and it seems to be correct. If you think that this a potential solution, may be you could accept it in order other MSE users kno it. Cheers :-)

Comment: Hello, maybe I am thinking wrong, but if you substitute $x=2y^2$ and you are considering $\sqrt(x)$ then you should not end up with a $y^2$ term.